# PCB - High current PTH

Tags: power, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, high-current

Some power boards are failing a high current (lightning) test where an MOV lead is used to transfer the current to the bottom of the board - see MOV lead and pad attached.

The issue seems to be that the manufacturer can only guarantee 70% wicking over the solder wave and the small section of PTH that is solder free is not able to carry sufficient current (even a filled barrel with a concave joint as shown is not sufficient).

Hand soldering the top of the lead passes the test.

While I will be working with the manufacturer to try and improve wicking I was hoping that some on this list might have ideas for a solution that did not require manual soldering.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: added layout for clarity

Edit: Has anyone used a rivet type solution for transferring high current?

[image: Fried Solder Joint]
[image: Added image of layout for reference]

Comment: How much current? The usual solution is multiple vias, and you can get copper-filled ones: http://www.thinfilm.com/vias_solid.html

Comment: As far as I can see its not the thru-hole that's failing, its the copper track leading up to it. I'd guess that the extra solder from hand-soldering makes that last tiny section of track just the extra bit beefier and so survives the extra current. maybe clear a section of solder mask and cut a little slot in your paste stencil to get some solder there when you do the SMD parts - although stopping the paste from running down the hole will be fun ...

Comment: @PJC50 Thanks For your reply. It's a lightning test. I find it difficult to get information on how vias behave with pulses of high current. This is a high volume-low cost board which rules out filled vias though.

Comment: @brhans Thanks, good points. I've added an image of the copper connection to the pad for clarity. I'm relying on analysis from the manufacturer and the hardware engineers (I have not seen any boards), I'd trust their results (they would probably prefer if the tracking was to blame..). coincidentally, adding a paste aperture had been suggested in an effort to get a better fillet to the top of the board (rather than for thickening the trace) but with the reflow happening before the wave I can't see it working.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, I use several large-size vias when I need to ensure a reliable high-current path between top and bottom layers on a PCB.

Large size, for me, is a 0.035" (~0.90 mm) hole with at least a 0.02" (~0.50 mm) anulus in the solder-mask around the hole. Plaster as many vias around the component lead as you have room - at least 4 or 5.

I find that we get 100% fill on vias when wave-soldering our boards.

Comment: I agree, you should use a bunch of vias. I would use a via size calculator to determine how big one via would have to be, and then decide from there what size to use and how many: http://circuitcalculator.com/wordpress/2006/03/12/pcb-via-calculator/

Comment: Hi, I've added "lightning" test to the post - should have had it in from the start. I don't think that vias barrels can handle this test. Filled vias might work if they could be consistently filled completely (although, would the lower conduction of the solder come into play?).